# Proof of commutativity for complex numbers help

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I just started Linear Algebra and my algebra is a little rusty. However, was going over the proof of associativity for complex number and while I was able to do it, I got stuck on the way they do it in the book.

Let
$$
\alpha=x_1+y_1i\\
\beta=x_2+y_2i\\
\lambda=x_3+y_3i\\ 
$$

where 
$$
x_1,x_2,x_3
$$ and $$
y_1,y_2,y_3
$$ are real numbers. Then
$$
\begin{align}
(\alpha\beta)\lambda &= ((x_1x_2−y_1y_2)+(x_1y_2+y_1x_2)i)(x_3+y_3i)\\&=((x_1x_2−y_1y_2)x_3−(x_1y_2+y_1x_2)y_3)+((x_1x_2−y_1y_2)x_3+(x_1y_2+y_1x_2)y_3)i.
\end{align}
$$

The part that I am struggling with here is:
$$
\begin{align}
&=((x_1x_2−y_1y_2)x_3−(x_1y_2+y_1x_2)y_3)+((x_1x_2−y_1y_2)x_3+(x_1y_2+y_1x_2)y_3)i.
\end{align}
$$

Basically I don't understand how we go here from the previous line. Maybe I have been staring at this for a while.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: With $x1$ you probably mean $x_1$ (written `x_1`) etc. Please correct this and also delete unnecessary repetitions to improve the readability of the post.

Comment: Also, you are checking associativity and not commutativity.

Comment: Do you know that the property holds for the real numbers? How do you define complex multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

$$
(x+iy)(z+iw)=xz+i(wx+yz)-yw
$$
Quite similarly 
$$
(z+iw)(x+iy)=zx+i(zy+xw)-wy
$$
since each of the products are real and thus commute, we have equality of real ad imaginary parts in the two expressions.

Comment: op is trying to check associativity, not commutativity

Comment: Do we know what the question is asking?